# Not able to connect to SFTP( via jumhost) using Apache camel

Tags: java, apache-camel, sftp

I am using Apache camel FTP and AWS module (v2.18 ) to create a route between SFTP and AWS S3. Connection to SFTP location is established via ssh jump-host.

Able to connect via Unix command :

```
    sftp -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null 
      -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no 
      -i /path/to/host/private-key-file 
        -o 'ProxyCommand=ssh 
            -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null 
            -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no 
            -i /path/to/jumphost/private-key-file
            -l jumphostuser jump.host.com nc sftp.host.com 22' sftp-user@sftp.host.com
```

However I am getting error while connecting using Apache camel :

```
      Cannot connect/login to: sftp://sftp-user@sftp.host.com:22
```

For testing purposes I tried connecting to SFTP using Spring -Integration and I was able to do it successfully using the same proxy implementation (JumpHostProxyCommand) mentioned below.

Below is the Spring boot + Apache Camel code that I have been using:

Jsch proxy :

```
      import com.jcraft.jsch.*;

      class JumpHostProxyCommand implements Proxy {

                String command;
                Process p = null;
                InputStream in = null;
                OutputStream out = null;

                public JumpHostProxyCommand(String command) {
                    this.command = command;
                }

                public void connect(SocketFactory socket_factory, String host, int port, int timeout) throws Exception {


                    String cmd = command.replace("%h", host);
                    cmd = cmd.replace("%p", new Integer(port).toString());

                    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
                    log.debug("Process returned by proxy command {} , {}", command,  p);
                    in = p.getInputStream();
                    log.debug("Input stream returned by proxy {}", in);
                    out = p.getOutputStream();
                    log.debug("Output stream returned by proxy {}", out);
                }

                public Socket getSocket() {
                    return null;
                }

                public InputStream getInputStream() {
                    return in;
                }

                public OutputStream getOutputStream() {
                    return out;
                }

                public void close() {
                    try {
                        if (p != null) {
                            p.getErrorStream().close();
                            p.getOutputStream().close();
                            p.getInputStream().close();
                            p.destroy();
                            p = null;
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Spring boot camel Configuration :

```
    @Configuration
    public class CamelConfig {

        @Autowired
        DataSource dataSource;


        @Bean(name = "jdbcMsgIdRepo")
        public JdbcMessageIdRepository JdbcMessageIdRepository() {
          return new JdbcMessageIdRepository(dataSource,"jdbc-repo");
        }

        @Bean(name = "s3Client")
        public AmazonS3 s3Client() {
          return new AmazonS3Client();
        }

        @Bean(name="jumpHostProxyCommand")
        JumpHostProxyCommand jumpHostProxyCommand()
        {
          String proxykeyFilePath = "/path/to/jumphost/private-key-file";

          String command = "ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /proxy/host/key/path  -l  jumphostuser  jump.host.com  nc %h %p";
          log.debug("JumpHostProxyCommand : " + command);
          return new JumpHostProxyCommand(command);
        }

      }
```

Camel Route builder :

```
          @Component
          public class FtpRouteInitializer extends RouteBuilder {

            @Value("${s3.bucket.name}")
            private String s3Bucket;

            @Autowired
            private JdbcMessageIdRepository repo;


            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {

              String ftpRoute =  "sftp://sftp-user@sftp.host.com:22/?" 
                  + "delay=300s" 
                  + "&noop=true"
                  + "&idempotentRepository=#jdbcMsgIdRepo" 
                  + "&idempotentKey=${file:name}-${file:modified}"
                  + "&proxy=#jumpHostProxyCommand" 
                  + "&privateKeyUri=file:/path/to/host/private-key-file"
                  + "&jschLoggingLevel=DEBUG"
                  + "&knownHostsFile=/dev/null"
                  + "&initialDelay=60s"
                  + "&autoCreate=false"
                  + "&preferredAuthentications=publickey";

              from(ftpRoute)
              .routeId("FTP-S3")
              .setHeader(S3Constants.KEY, simple("${file:name}"))
              .to("aws-s3://" + s3ucket + "?amazonS3Client=#s3Client")
              .log("Uploaded ${file:name} complete.");
            }

          }
```

build.gradle file:

```
        task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
            gradleVersion = '2.5'
        }

        ext {
                springBootVersion = "1.4.1.RELEASE"
                awsJavaSdkVersion = "1.10.36"
                postgresVersion = "11.2.0.3.0"
                jacksonVersion = "2.8.4"
                sl4jVersion = "1.7.21"
                junitVersion = "4.12"
                camelVersion ="2.18.0"
        }

        buildscript {
            repositories {
                mavenCentral()
            }

            dependencies {
                classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.4.1.RELEASE")
            }
        }

        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }

        apply plugin: 'java'
        apply plugin: 'eclipse'
        apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8

        springBoot {
            executable = true
        }

        dependencies {

            //logging 
            compile("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.3")
            compile("ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.1.3")
            compile("org.slf4j:slf4j-api:$sl4jVersion")

            //Spring boot 
            compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:$springBootVersion")
            compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:$springBootVersion")
            compile("org.apache.camel:camel-spring-boot-starter:$camelVersion")

            //Jdbc
            compile("postgresql:postgresql:9.0-801.jdbc4")

            //Camel
            compile("org.apache.camel:camel-ftp:$camelVersion")
            compile("org.apache.camel:camel-aws:$camelVersion")
            compile("org.apache.camel:camel-core:$camelVersion")
            compile("org.apache.camel:camel-spring-boot:$camelVersion")
            compile("org.apache.camel:camel-sql:$camelVersion")


            //Aws sdk
             compile("com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:$awsJavaSdkVersion")

            //Json
             compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:$jacksonVersion")
            compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:$jacksonVersion")
            compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:$jacksonVersion")
            compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:$jacksonVersion")

            //Swagger
            compile("io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.0.2")
            compile("io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.0.2")

            //utilities
             compile('org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.6')
             compile("org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.1")
             compile("org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4")



            //Junit
            testCompile("junit:junit:$junitVersion")
            testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:$springBootVersion")
            testCompile("org.mockito:mockito-all:1.10.19")

        }
```

I have been struggling for last 2 days to find out the root cause of the error, any help on this issue is really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding jump host configuration in the ssh config file on the machine where you are running this code. You shall be able to transparently connect to the server using the jump host for the host(s) specified in the config file without needing to specify any proxy or jump host in the sftp command.

An example config to setup a dynamic jump host is as follows:

```
Host sftp.host.com
user sftp-user
IdentityFile /home/sftp-user/.ssh/id_rsa
ProxyCommand ssh sftp-user@jump.host.com nc %h %p 2> /dev/null
ForwardAgent yes
```

You can add multiple hosts or regex pattern in the Host line. This entry needs to be done in ~/.ssh/config file (create this file if not already present).